# httpdocs/cache entries in the apache error log

Tags: apache, centos

We have a LAMP environment for our website.

Recently we started seeing some new error_log entries which are similar to the following entry:

```
 [Tue May 08 17:30:37 2012] [error] [client 123.123.123.123] 
 File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/cache, 
 referer: http://www.domain.com/my.php
```

The thing is we do not have a folder named "cache", and have no reference to a folder with that name. No new configuration changes.

These entries are from different IP's and dispersed over time.

What could have triggered these entries?

Our web server is behind a netscaler. Could it have started doing this?
We have APC running. Could APC be doing this? We are on APC 3.1.9, PHP 5.3.13

Comment: Exactly the same issue. We also have APC (3.1.3p1), PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze9 on debian. No idea about the origin of the issue. :(

Comment: Pick one of the IP's and grep the apache access_log to see what else they've requested. If it's nothing legitimate I suspect your servers are just being probed by a very naughty individual, possibly via a botnet.

Comment: See also:  Also see: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30579/new-requests-for-cache-urls

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your page "www.mydomain.com/my.php" had a reference to "httpdocs/cache" at some point of time. Search engines like google cache a lot of your pages. So it is possible that someone (person or a bot) is accessing the "httpdocs/cache" contents.

Many companies, have crawlers that crawl the web for information. That may be the reason you are getting repeated requests to a non existent file.

You can check the access_logs to get more information about the user/bot. If you find something suspicious you might want to block access for that client using a IPTable rule.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue, and I'm getting this queries of certain pattern
Apache **access.log** is full of **edit** and **cache** unexistent folders.

```
example.com/edit
example.com/cache
example.com/cache/6dd9aa0b0606270d0875acb21546bedb (If i create such folder)
```

Last line is hash, in my example i figured random hash for demonstration, do not search it.

The problem is, that this queries may be too frequent looking even like hammering. I have sometimes up to 20-30 req/s with "/edit" query.

So far, I'm just blocking such bots but I'm very curious to get any answers